# Parsing JSON from the google maps DistanceMatrix api in android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I am new to android development and new to JSON. I am using the google maps distance matrix api. I have the JSON download into a JSONObject properly I believe.(I stole the code to do it from another post). However I can not seem to parse the JSON properly. I have been working at this for a few day and am completely stumped. I make the following call to google below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=1600%20pennsylvania%20avenue&destinations=1500%20college%20street&mode=driving&units=imperial
```

The output is this:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "1500 College Street, Beaumont, TX 77701, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Hagerstown, MD 21742, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,306 mi",
                  "value" : 2102536
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "18 hours 48 mins",
                  "value" : 67684
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I have tried:

1.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("rows");
JSONArray routes = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
stringBuilder.append(routes.getJSONObject(0).getString("text"));
```

2.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("rows");
JSONObject routes = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
stringBuilder.append(routes.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text"));
```

3.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("elements");                    stringBuilder.append(routes.getJSONObject(0).getString("text"));
```

I have tried more but those seem to me like they should work. It seemed that to me rows is an array and elements is an array as well. So it would follow that I would need to get rows out of the original JSONObject then get the element array out of the row array then get the distance object out of that array, then finally get the text value and add it to the string builder I created earlier.
Were did I go wrong? thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: *I have tried just about everything and it keeps throwing different exceptions.* then show us what had you tried and what exception you are getting ... also before asking google for those exceptions ...

Comment: I edited it to show some of it. I did google the exceptions. However I didn't think it made any sense. For example in case one it says the thing in position 0 of the jsonArray object is not an array. However wouldn't the thing be elements which is an array?

Comment: `rows` is an array. then *first element* is an object. then `elements` property of this object is an array. then *first element* is an object with `distance` property ...  which is an object ... which have `text` property ... in 2nd you are almost there ... but you forgot about `elements` array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what worked with me

```
//httpResponse is the output of google api
JSONObject jsonRespRouteDistance = new JSONObject(httpResponse)
                                        .getJSONArray("rows")
                                        .getJSONObject(0)
                                        .getJSONArray ("elements")
                                        .getJSONObject(0)
                                        .getJSONObject("distance");

String distance = jsonRespRouteDistance.get("text").toString();

/* 
* For distance, below is only partial solution as the 
* output to string destination_addr will contain square brackets [] and double codes ""
* Eg. [ "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Hagerstown, MD 21742, USA" ]
* 
*/
String destination_addr = new JSONObject(httpResponse)
                            .get("destination_addresses")
                            .toString();
```

[UPDATE]

Assuming we have only one destination address and not multiple. A little string manipulation gets us the clean string string without codes " and brackets []

```
StringBuilder stringBuilderDestinationAddr = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < destination_addr.length(); i++)
    if (destination_addr.charAt(i) != '[' && destination_addr.charAt(i) != ']' && destination_addr.charAt(i) != '"')
         stringBuilderDestinationAddr.append(pickup_addr.destination_addr (i));

String strCleanDestination = stringBuilderDestinationAddr.toString();
```